# splitting a pstricks-picture into several, stepwise

Tags: pstricks

When explaining diagrams (in Economics), making them more complex in a  step-by-step manner is often useful for students. What I usually do is to draw a pstricks image (that may contain a lot of details) and when done, I repeatedly copy&paste the code and comment out the parts that I want to be displayed later on.

A simple example for this procedure is

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
% always show this
\rput(0,0){\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)}
%\psgrid(0,0)(8,8) 
%step1
\psline(1,1)(5,6)
%step2 - final
%\psline(1,6)(6,1)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
% always show this
\rput(0,0){\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)}
%\psgrid(0,0)(8,8) 
%step1
\psline(1,1)(5,6)
%step2 - final
\psline(1,6)(6,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is a pdf with extension ...-pics.pdf with two images on separate pages that I can include elsewhere with \includegraphics[page=1]{...-pics.pdf} and \includegraphics[page=2]{...-pics.pdf}

My question: Is there a more elegant way to do this where it is enough to draw the image just once and then tell pstricks that the image should be produced in different versions/steps? Something like

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
\stepwise[0]
\rput(0,0){\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)}
\stepwise[1]
\psline(1,1)(5,6)
\stepwise[2]
\psline(1,6)(6,1)
\end{pspicture}
```

Using several \newcommands and then reusing code is an option, but I am looking for an easier way to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `beamer` documentclass with a plain canvas:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\frame[plain]{%
    \psset{unit=0.75}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(10,10)
    \rput(0,0){\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(8,8)}
    \psline(1,1)(5,6)          \pause
    \psline(1,6)(6,1)
    \end{pspicture}%
}   
\end{document}
```

You can run `pdfcrop` on that document if you want to delete the whitespace.

Comment: thanks a lot, sounds like a straightforward workflow. However, if the main file is called stepwise.tex, I get stepwise.pdf with only one page and also only one of the two \pslines. However, stepwise-pics.pdf contains two pages with two properly cropped images. Hm - how to make sure that one can see the entire image in the main pdf, too? Because this is what is shown by my LaTeX-Editor....

Comment: Adding for every pause command another frame containing a pspicture like this 
    \frame[plain]{%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \end{pspicture}
    }

somehow "solves" the problem.

Comment: Found it: it is a problem with auto-pst-pdf. But using XeLaTeX for typesetting really solves the problem. (Hopefully with not too many side-effects.) THANKS!

Comment: Without using package `auto-pst-pdf` and running `xelatex` you'll get a pdf with two pages.

Comment: yes, thank you. (I then miss my multi-page pdf, though.)